# Can I turn this dataframe into line graph

Tags: python, pandas, graph

Is there any way I can get this dataframe into a line graph where there is a separate line for each TypeLoc, measuring Value on the Y-axis, and year going along the x-axis in python using pandas?
I have tried so many ways but very new to python so not getting anywhere.
I have spent about 5 hours trying to figure it out and this seemed like the best place to ask.

```
  TESTDATA = StringIO("""DateCode;Value;TypeLoc;Expend_or_Visit;
2014;186;Seaside - beach;Expenditure;
2019;1456;Small town;Expenditure;
2016;4916;All areas;Expenditure;
2018;5474;All areas;Expenditure;
2013;217;Seaside - beach;Expenditure;
2018;6;Seaside - other;Expenditure;
2018;1234;Small town;Expenditure;
2015;230;Seaside resort or town;Expenditure;
2016;302;Seaside resort or town;Expenditure;
2019;359;Seaside resort or town;Expenditure;
2017;458;Seaside resort or town;Expenditure;
2015;3922;All areas;Expenditure;
2014;5020;All areas;Expenditure;
2013;4647;All areas;Expenditure;
2016;1037;Small town;Expenditure;
2013;68;Seaside - other;Expenditure;
2013;1035;Small town;Expenditure;
2017;46;Seaside - beach;Expenditure;
2019;35;Seaside - other;Expenditure;
2015;914;Small town;Expenditure;
2016;32;Seaside - other;Expenditure;
2016;249;Seaside - beach;Expenditure;
2015;36;Seaside - other;Expenditure;
2014;128;Seaside - other;Expenditure;
2017;75;Seaside - other;Expenditure;
2015;81;Seaside - beach;Expenditure;
2019;237;Seaside - beach;Expenditure;
2018;151;Seaside - beach;Expenditure;
2019;457;Village;Expenditure;
2015;308;Village;Expenditure;
2019;3400;City/large town;Expenditure;
2018;3111;City/large town;Expenditure;
2017;1377;Small town;Expenditure;
2017;883;Village;Expenditure;
2014;1398;Small town;Expenditure;
2014;2873;City/large town;Expenditure;
2015;2254;City/large town;Expenditure;
2017;3379;City/large town;Expenditure;
2016;2630;City/large town;Expenditure;
2014;286;Seaside resort or town Expenditure;
2013;2850;City/large town;Expenditure;
2013;206;Seaside resort or town;Expenditure;
2017;778;Rural countryside;Expenditure;
2016;520;Rural countryside;Expenditure;
2017;5995;All areas;Expenditure;
2019;429;Rural countryside;Expenditure;
2015;402;Rural countryside;Expenditure;
2018;228;Seaside resort or town;Expenditure;
2018;502;Rural countryside;Expenditure;
2016;482;Village;Expenditure;
2014;510;Village;Expenditure;
2018;651;Village;Expenditure;
2013;483;Village;Expenditure;
2014;612;Rural countryside;Expenditure;
2019;5777;All areas;Expenditure;
2013;545;Rural countryside;Expenditure;
     """)
```

link to full data set https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bRaq8I3JW6yZ0oucoVaFVH4ldd-HxAUZUBgeUk7KBgs/edit?usp=sharing
(I couldn't read this into my notebook hence manually entering everything.)
dataframe [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l68sB.png):
[image: dataframe]

*Tried to go back through my code to get what I've attempted from it -
this was my best attempt which is still miles off:

```
df.set_index('TypeLoc', inplace=True)

df_expend = df_expend.transpose()

df_expend = df.query('Expend_or_Visit == "Expenditure"')

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df_expend.plot(kind='line')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please provide  the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  Post your best attempt, and we have something to work with.  Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorial resources.

Comment: I can't access the google-doc. It's password protected.

Comment: Sorry, should be fixed now. Not sure I'm cut out for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to do that. You need to pivot the dataframe first, and plot it later:

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(TESTDATA), sep=";")
df = df[["DateCode", "Value", "TypeLoc"]].pivot(index = "DateCode", columns = "TypeLoc")
df = df.droplevel(0, axis=1)
for col in df.columns:
    plt.plot(df.index, df[col], label =col)
plt.show()
```

The output, with the limited sample data, is:

[image]

To run this code against the larger data set (the one in the link), use:

```
df = pd.read_csv("scot_stats - Sheet1.csv", header = 1)
df = df[df.Units == "million pounds (GBP)"]

df = df[["DateCode", "Value", "TypeLoc"]].pivot(index = "DateCode", columns = "TypeLoc")
df = df.droplevel(0, axis=1)
for col in df.columns:
    plt.plot(df.index, df[col], label =col)
plt.show()
```

The output is below. You can create a separate graph for visits by changing the condition on the second line.

[image]

Comment: thanks for your help. It's now giving me this error: ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape. Any thoughts?
There is an entry for each DateCode for each TypeLoc with different values.

Comment: please include a large data sample (as text), so I can reproduce the issue on my side.

Comment: thank you! I have edited the original post since there's not many characters in a comment.

Comment: Thanks Roy2012. Still getting the error: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape. Will keep playing about and hopefully get it.

Comment: I was not able to access the document you posted on google - maybe there's additional data there?

Comment: Your 2nd one looks like how it should mine just isn't doing it. 
I've given access to anyone with a link so should be able to access it now.
I used this line to read in my text 
df = pd.read_csv(TESTDATA, sep=";")
when I do the one you suggested it's giving me another error:
TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not _io.StringIO

- think there's too many errors in my code might have to go back and start again.

Comment: The issue you're facing is because the full data - the one on Google - contains two values for every year - TypeLoc combination. There's one with "million pounds (GBP) ", and one with "Million Visits". This column, called 'unit' is missing from the sample data in the question.

Comment: I've checked and I removed that column from the text file before putting it in the notebook. The only columns I've included are the ones in the sample data.

Comment: So ... which value are you interested in? GBP or visits? You currently have two values for each year/location combination.

Comment: I would be looking to do one for GBP and one for visits, but they could be done on separate graphs

Comment: I slept on it and tried again this morning after splitting the dataframe and it worked! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import io

TESTDATA = io.StringIO("""DateCode;Value;TypeLoc;Expend_or_Visit;
2014;186;Seaside - beach;Expenditure;
2019;1456;Small town;Expenditure;
2016;4916;All areas;Expenditure;
2018;5474;All areas;Expenditure;
2013;217;Seaside - beach;Expenditure;
2018;6;Seaside - other;Expenditure;
2018;1234;Small town;Expenditure;
 """)

df = pd.read_csv(TESTDATA, sep =";")

sns.lineplot(x='DateCode', y='Value', hue= 'TypeLoc',data=df)
```